# Adding a countdown timer to textblock WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, countdown

I want to implement a countdown timer that use to work on CMD  into a textblock with wpf.

I can't figure it out how to implement that code into a textblock.

```
  DateTime daysLeft1 = DateTime.Parse("1/02/2022 12:00:01 AM");
                DateTime startDate1 = DateTime.Now;


                TimeSpan t = daysLeft1 - startDate1;
                string countDown = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes, {3} Seconds until launch.",
                    t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

Thank you for your help ! .

EDIT: The code Below seem to work but I have error  CS0120

"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TextBlock.Text' "

```
public partial class justdancetrailer : Window
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private readonly DateTime daysLeft;

    public justdancetrailer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        daysLeft = DateTime.Parse("1/02/2022 12:00:00 AM");

        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0); ;
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan t = daysLeft.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if (t.Seconds >= 0)
        {
            string countDown = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes, {3} Seconds until launch.",
                t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);

            



            TextBlock.Text = countDown;

            daysLeft.AddSeconds(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            Timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void trailer_play(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        trailer.Play();
    }

    private void trailer_stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        trailer.Stop();
        trailer.Close();
    }

    private void trailer_pause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        trailer.Pause();

    }
    private void ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        trailer.Volume = e.NewValue;
    }


}
```

}

And this is the TextBlock :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="countDown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="250" Height="58" Foreground="White"
               Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"
               Text=""/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you need an interval equals 1 second.

```
    private readonly DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private readonly DateTime daysLeft;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        daysLeft = DateTime.Parse("1/02/2022 12:00:00 AM");
        
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0); ;
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan t = daysLeft.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if (t.Seconds >= 0)
        {
            string countDown = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes, {3} Seconds until launch.",
                t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);

            textBlock.Text = countDown;
            daysLeft.AddSeconds(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            Timer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seem to be a pretty good way to do it. I got a error  *CS0120* telling me that  
"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TextBlock.Text' "  I try several thing and google what it mean but coudln't find it  *** I copy paste the code you send me :) 

Thank you again !

Comment: are u using binding? this code worked for me.

Comment: what is binding ? :$

Comment: Data binding in XAML... anyways please create a new WPF project and copy paste my code to MainWindow.xaml.cs then add add a TextBlock with a Name "textBlock" to the main Window Grid. it should work!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help I was able to make it work with the last comment. I didn't change my TextBlock name :P

Comment: I'll be there any time <3. Please Mark the answer as The Answer and Upvote it if it helped!

Comment: Thank you Sorry I didn't know that there was a place to mark an answer I just did it. Have a good day !